# boto3: how to start instance with elastic gpu?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

AWS docs States:

> "You can launch an instance and associate it with an elastic GPU
>   during launch.".

But I can't find if it's possible to do with boto3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
'ElasticGpuSpecifications': [
                {
                    'Type': 'string'
                },
            ],
```

**- ElasticGpuSpecifications (list) --**

The elastic GPU specification.

- (dict) --

  Describes an elastic GPU.
- **Type** (String) --

  The elastic GPU type.

Refer this [Boto Documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html)

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean in `create_launch_template`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Host:
 Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
 Properties:
   ...

   ElasticGpuSpecifications:
      - Type: "eg1.xlarge"
   ...
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?